# How to get Instagram post URL from Facebook Graph media_id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm using [Instagram Mentions API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/mentions) and was able to obtain FB *media_id* for couple Instagram posts.

I need *media_id* to get post content via [/user/mentioned_media](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/mentioned_media). Unfortunately that endpoint does not provide *ig_id* or *shortcode* or *permalink* which I need.

Is there a way to get Instagram Post URL with FB Graph API *media_id*?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media#metadata ...?

Comment: @cbroe, I have this same issue and that endpoint /media doesn't seem to work.  You can only get media data for posts that you created.  What about posts received from mention webhook?  the mentioned_media endpoint doesn't provide the post URL and the /media endpoint doesn't allow me to call it for a post from another person.  so it seems.  I would also like to see an answer to this question

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you can get media metadata (and all comments/replies) when someone @-mentions you in a non-owned-media comment by using a query like below.

You would use your own instagram business account id for the first number (the path component), and you'd use the `comment_id` you received from the webhook comment-mention notification as the second number:

```
/12345678901234567890?fields=mentioned_comment.comment_id(9876543210987654321){id,text,username,timestamp,media{id,media_type,media_url,permalink,username,like_count,comments_count,comments{id,text,username,user{id,username},like_count,timestamp,replies{id,text,username,user{id,username},like_count,timestamp}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you check the documentation for `GET /{ig-user-id}?fields=mentioned_media` at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/mentioned_media , it says that `fields` is for a IGMedia node, even though its **not docummented properply** in the above url, you can use the available fields of an IGMedia Node as described here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media.

Hence you can get the permalink by asking for it in the fields param like this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/{YOUR_IG_USER_ID}?fields=mentioned_media.media_id(18024497428601371){id,caption,permalink,media_url}
```

and you get a  graph api response

```
{
  "mentioned_media": {
    "id": "18024497428601371",
    "caption": "example text",
    "permalink": "https://www.instagram.com/p/SHORT_CODE/",
    "media_url": "SOME_URL"
  },
  "id": "YOUR_IG_USER_ID"
}
```

P.S It will also only work if the user has mentioned your ig account in the media caption

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a way you can get Instagram post URL associated with a media if you know the media id.

You can also get more information (all its fields and edges) on media. See the docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media)

You can get the Instagram post URL by making a GET request to `/{ig-media-id}`

**Sample Request:**

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/{{media_id}}?fields=permalink, shortcode&access_token={{ACCESS_TOKEN}}
```

**Sample Response:**

```
{
    "permalink": "https://www.instagram.com/p/Clxsi5Pol2_/",
    "shortcode": "Clxsi5Pol2_",
    "id": "17xxx59557977xxx"
}
```

The value of the `permalink` is the valid public URL  for the post.
You can also use the `shortcode` returned to construct the URL by concatenating the shortcode to `https://www.instagram.com/p/`.

Comment: this only works for media created by your own account, doesn't work for media mentions, which the OP is asking about, it will throw an object-id doesnt exist error